# Testng split dataProvider between parallel methods

Tags: parallel-processing, testng, dataprovider

I have a dataProvider which is reading the data from a text file.

```
@DataProvider (name = "dynamicDP", parallel = true)
    public Iterator<Object> matchIDs() throws IOException {
      final List<Object> list = new ArrayList<>();

        for (final String line: Files.readAllLines(Paths.get("C:\\mypath"),
            StandardCharsets.UTF_8))
            list.add(new Object[]{ line});

        return list.iterator();    
}
```

My text file is really simple it only contains these data below (each pair of letters on a separate line):

> AA BB CC DD EE FF GG HH II KK

Here is my test class:

```
public class dataProviderParallelTest {

 @Test (dataProvider="dynamicDP")
 public void verifyDPdata(String comingFromDP){ 
 System.out.printf("%nDP#1..: "+comingFromDP);  
 }


 @Test (dataProvider="dynamicDP")
 public void verifyDPdata2(String comingFromDP){
 System.out.printf("%nDP#2..: "+comingFromDP);
 }  
}
```

Here is the output:

```
[TestNG] Running:
  C:\projects\test\currentTest.xml

DP#1..: AA
DP#2..: BB
DP#1..: BB
DP#2..: AA
DP#1..: CC
DP#2..: CC
DP#1..: DD
DP#1..: EE
DP#2..: EE
DP#2..: DD
DP#1..: FF
DP#2..: FF
DP#1..: GG
DP#1..: HH
DP#2..: HH
DP#2..: GG
DP#1..: II
DP#2..: II
DP#1..: KK
DP#2..: KK
===============================================
Regression
Total tests run: 20, Failures: 0, Skips: 0
===============================================
```

And here is my XML file that I'm using to start my test:

```
<!DOCTYPE suite SYSTEM "http://testng.org/testng-1.0.dtd" >

<suite name="Regression" parallel="methods" thread-count="2" data-provider-thread-count="2">

    <test name="smokeTest11">   
        <classes>   
        <class name="regression.bo.dataProviderParallelTest"/>
        </classes>
    </test>

</suite>
```

**What I have tried:**
I've read this article: [cedricBlog](http://beust.com/weblog/2009/04/22/advanced-parallel-testing-with-testng-and-data-providers/)
and this stackoverflow post:[stackOverFlow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15232664/testng-parallel-runs-with-a-single-threaded-data-provider/15232830#15232830)

What am I trying to achieve:
I am trying to share the data between the two threads. At the moment I just achieved both of the threads to execute the same data provided by the DP. My aim is to split the data between the two methods and have an output like this (DP data shared between the 2 methods):

```
DP#1..: AA
DP#2..: BB
DP#1..: DD
DP#2..: EE
DP#1..: CC
DP#2..: GG
DP#1..: KK
DP#1..: HH
DP#2..: II
DP#2..: FF
```

Is this even possible or am I missing something? Thanks in advance for your help!

Comment: Would skipping the other method be ok for you?

Comment: Hi Grzergorz, thank you very much for your interest. Unfortunately no, because the ultimate intent is to execute these simultaneously at different grid nodes. But regardless, thanks for your help. I'm starting to think; that what I am trying to achieve is not good practice with a dataProvider. I have an 'alternative' solution but is a Java solution not a testNG solution. Anyways, will still vote up, anyone who can solve this :)

Comment: Will also vote up, I have managed to skip those tests (using a synchronized Collection), but I know that this is not a desired result. What is your Java solution?

Comment: Very briefly my alternative, java solution is the following. Read all lines get the size and divide by 10 (deal with remainder) and create 10 sets of data. Then I'll pass these to 10 different providers which in turn will feed 10 selenium grid nodes performing automated tests. This is exactly what I was trying to achieve with the shared data provider above only in that case it will be much more dynamic (on a one to one basis)..

Comment: Looks like divide and conquer, which is good, but do you repeat any code, when you write "10 different" data providers?

Comment: No, from the performance perspective, yes from the literal perspective! All tests are pushed concurrently to the grid hub and this is the one which decides on which node to forward on the tests (if not busy --> forward). I got 10 at the moment running on VMware, so my plan is to run only 1 test and then holy copy-paste it another 9 times (can be done as methods or classes) and feed them with the DPs. The only reason I will copy paste the code is that testNG executes in parallel tests as methods or classes (or instances..)

Comment: So basically the same code is run, but with different data?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, posting and my solution for reference. In short it is this. Count the lines in the file, and start reading 1 line at a time (from 10 different threads) until you reach the EOF. Here it is:

```
  public volatile int currentLine=0;
  public static Object writeLock = new Object();
  public static Object readLock = new Object();
  public long currentThread =  Thread.currentThread().getId();



 @Test(invocationCount = 50)
  public void readOneLineGetID() throws IOException{

  countLines();           
  if(currentLine==noOfLines){throw new SkipException("%nSkipping this test method as we got all the records we need.");}
  long threadID = Thread.currentThread().getId();

    synchronized(readLock){ 
         if(currentLine<noOfLines){
        System.out.printf("%nCurrent thread is..: "+ threadID);
         readASpecificLineFromATextFile(currentLine);   
         System.out.printf("%n----------------------------------------------------------");     
         }
     }

     synchronized(writeLock){
     currentLine++;         
     }     

  }
```

So I have 10 of these methods and I am pushing my tests concurrently onto a grid hub which then uses 10 different data providers to feed the nodes.

*Only, minor point is the invocationCount (ideally i should divide by 10 and then set the invocation count on every single method accordingly; but as I don't have time to re-invent the wheel and this runs very very fast (only dealing with 200 line files normally, I decided to skip the rest of methods after the line number reaches EOF ;) )*

Here is the output (10 methods, with 50 invocation count finding 10 mockup lines from my file and skipping the rest):

[image]

After some tinkering with the sync, beatiful!!! :)

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Take the method as parameter to your dataprovider.  Divide your data in two lists, whichever way you like.  Based on method name, return one list to each.

eg.

For example, the following code prints the name of the test method inside its @DataProvider:

```
@DataProvider(name = "dynamicDP", parallel = true)
public Object[][] dynamicDP(Method m) {
  System.out.println(m.getName());
  //Divide list in two lists
  if (m.getName().equals("Met1")
     return list1
  else
     return list2
}

@Test(dataProvider="dynamicDP")
public void test1(String s) {
}

@Test(dataProvider="dynamicDP")
public void test2(String s) {
}
```

HTH

Comment: Good attempt, thanks niharika; I've voted it up as this solves the problem. However, eventually I will run these 'lists' onto 10 nodes (i.e. 10 different methods) and although it is not an issue dividing by 10 and dealing with the remainder; it is not exactly parallel execution at its best. I found an even better (for my needs), more dynamic custom solution which will deal with the data on a line-by-line basis. Will post soon! Thanks again for your help guys, much appreciated for your effort & time!